# What's the difference between different NodeJS HTTP server ports and which one should I use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, port

What does a port change about my server? I've seen a lot of people use port 3000 in their code. Any NodeJS server I make has at least two things: HTTP and Express.

Comment: Unless your endpoint is implementing a standardized service that is assigned to a standardized port, the port number is arbitrary.  So long as it is not in use by another application, it's available for use.  Edit: Quick wiki search for a listing of standardized ports https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: According to these answers, I think I understand the answer now. The port really doesn't change anything important in my use cases, it only changes the port number to put in my  URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is simply a communication endpoint for your application. Changing your port will have no affect on how your application runs. Note that most applications have ports that they use (for example Redis typically uses port 6379), but can be configured to use any port. I generally use port 8000, but you can pick any port you want as long as it's not taken by another application on your machine!

Answer (score 2):

It's the port that your server will listen on. So, if you are listening on port 2000, you would go to `http://YourDomain.com:2000`. Make sure the port you are listening on is open of course! Port 80 is the standard port for http, and port 443 for https.

I commonly see node sites using 8080 (which is an alternative to 80)

Answer (score 1):

**It changes nothing**, you can basically write any port and if the port is free, everything will be fine, you can read more about ports [here](https://whatismyipaddress.com/port) with very simple explanation